# Why is an email's `WordEditor.Application`'s `Selection` `Nothing` (`None`) unless its `Inspector` is first displayed in Outlook VBA?

Tags: python, vba, outlook, win32com

I am using `win32com`'s Python bindings for VBA. I am attempting to move to the end of a line with the end key in an Outlook email. I believe this requires me to get the `WordEditor` and use its `Application`'s `Selection`. Say `email` is the email created by `CreateItem`.

I tried to use

```py
email.GetInspector.WordEditor.Application.Selection.EndKey(Unit=6)
```

but unless the Outlook app is displayed first (`email.GetInspector.Display()`), `Selection` is `None` and therefore does not have an attribute `EndKey`.

Why is this and how can I work around it?

Comment: Do you get the same results if you try to automate Word without displaying any UI?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use the [Range.Select](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/word.range.select) method which selects the specified range to initialize the `Selection` object. For example:

```
Document.Paragraphs(1).Range.Select
```

Comment: No idea how I would've figured this out by the docs. Worked perfectly, thanks!